# Aligning bottoms of divs to same level

Tags: html, css, alignment

Is there any way to get comment divs bottom to the same level of buttons bottom line?

This is how it now works.
[Quick jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kirilt/t1em5h3d/)

```
.button_div {
  width: 54px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.comments {
  width: 320px;
  margin-right: -100px;
  height: 340px;
  background-color: #818181;
  float: left;
}

.comment_cont {
  float: right;
}
```

And this is how I want it to look.
[Accomplished with negative top margin](https://jsfiddle.net/kirilt/pqy7evkj/), but this approach don't work for me, because height of comment div may change.

Comment: They should be in the same div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` with `align-items: flex-end` on parent element.

```css
.comments {
  width: 320px;
  height: 340px;
  background-color: #818181;
}
.comment_cont {
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment_cont">
  <div class="button_div">
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="comments"></div>
</div>
```